# localizing default asp.net error messages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to localize validation error messages when filling a form using asp.net mvc.
I was able to localize messages which appear for form fields in models but some messages I couldn't find neither in models nor in javascript files.
I then found the solution to the problem in the following link:
http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2013/03/31/localizing-default-error-messages-in-asp-net-mvc-and-web-form.aspx 
The problem now is that I want to know the keys which the system has such as [FieldMustBeANumber] so I can localize them using the solution in the above link.
Thank you.

Comment: i would just make sure the thread is set appropriately.

Comment: @DanielA.White please read it now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing the error message in the model

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="The field \"{0}\" is required.")]
[Display(Name = "Comment text.")]
public string Text { get; set; }
```